# Unable to connect to serial console of instance on google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-networking

I have created a RHEL7 instance on GCP. Due to some changes in networking, I am not able to ping or ssh to the external IP of the instance.

I want to troubleshoot the instance, but the serial console connection is not working. I was able to connect to this instance before, but as I have observed, it seldom succeeds and fails.

Error:
You cannot connect to the serial console of the VM because of an unexpected error.Ensure serial console connectivity is enabled for this VM, wait a few moments and then try again (#79)

Is this a known issue? I have observed this quite frequently for many of my instances.

My network connectivity has good speed, so I don't think it's a problem.

Comment: Would you specify with details what networking change you did ? What kind of issue have you got with the serial console ?

Comment: I have 1 default and 3 private networks. I rename the private NICs and then restart google-network-setup service, so that the routing entries corresponding to new names get added, and then I can connect on all networks.

Comment: Sometimes the SSH connectivity gets lost for all my instances (even the instances without any nw changes). Then I couldn't even connect to the serial console.

Today I am seeing that I am able to connect via SSH to an instance, but can't open the serial console to check logs.

Comment: I see following message flooding system logs.
localhost kernel: [  766.829771] IPv4: martian source <IP1> from <IP2>, on dev eth0

Comment: If the serial console is not available I believe that apart from having net issue you might be facing hardware issue as well. Without serial console access it would be really difficult to debug your instance.I would suggest to make a copy of the disk then attach it to a new instance and just pass all the important date into the new instance.

Comment: `martian source` is one of your problems. You must get your network design correct before looking at serial port access.  All martian packets are dropped. This points to invalid addressing, router mis-configuration, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to use ssh or serial and getting the same error (#79).

For me te issue was our local UTM after i added an exception for *.cloud.google.com all is working.